# Accessing a C++ function from a CXX test

Tags: c++, cxxtest

I'm writing a few CXX unit tests for a class I have written.  I have never written CXX tests before (also this is the only framework I can use).  I am trying to call a function contained within my class so that I can test the output is what is expected, but I am unsure if you can do this, and if so, how.

```
Test.h:
class Test..... {
    public:
        std::string GenerateHash(const std::string& user, const std::string& url) const;
    ...
}


Test.cpp:
string
Test::GenerateHash(const string& user, const string& urrl) const {
    ...
 }
```

I have included the header file in the CXX test, but cannot access the GenerateHash function.

```
Test.cxx_h:
void testCheckHashGeneration( void ) {
    TS_ASSERT_EQUALS (GenerateHash("testuser", "http://www.stackoverflow.com"), "DFEGEC.....");
}

Error: error: âGenerateHashâ was not declared in this scope
```

I also tried:

```
Test.cxx_h:
void testCheckHashGeneration( void ) {
    Test test;
    TS_ASSERT_EQUALS (test->GenerateHash("testuser", "http://www.stackoverflow.com"), "DFEGEC.....");
}

Error: error: âTestâ has not been declared
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you instantiate the Test object?  Please provide more code.

Comment: How are you trying to access it? How doesn't it work? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, you're trying to call a member function without an instance of `Test`. You need a `Test` to call it on, as you've done in the second case.

In the second case, you're trying to call a member using the syntax for having a pointer to the object, '`->`', when you actually have an object. You want the second to look like this:

```
test.GenerateHash(...)
```

If you somehow had a Test*, then you could call it like

```
test->GenerateHash(...)
```

use `.` for objects, `->` for pointers to objects.

More code and error output would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the GenerateHash function can be a `static` method, then make it static.  Then call it using `Test::GenerateHash(/*your arguments*/);`

Considering the way you initially attempted to call `GenerateHash`, I would guess that this should be a static method.  If its execution does not depend on a particular instance of the `Test` class, then it can be static.

Otherwise, use `test.GenerateHash` rather than `test->GenerateHash`